# e.After.VoiceChannel.Name Discord.NET - Can't figure out null error

Tags: c#, nullreferenceexception, discord, discord.net

Before you judge me for posting ANOTHER NullReferenceException problem, please read my code. I've been googling NullReferenceException errors for a while now and, it doesn't explain why this specific section gives me an error.

```
    if (e.After.VoiceChannel.Name != null)
```

I've also looked at the documentation for Discord.NET, however, that has also yielded nothing. Here is the whole file.

```
using Discord;
using Discord.Commands;

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace DiscBot
{
    class myBot
    {
        DiscordClient discord;

        public myBot()
        {

            discord = new DiscordClient(x => 
            {
                x.LogLevel = LogSeverity.Info;
                x.LogHandler = Log;
            });

            discord.UsingCommands(x => 
            {
                x.PrefixChar = '~';
                x.AllowMentionPrefix = true;
                x.HelpMode = HelpMode.Public;
            });

            var commands = discord.GetService<CommandService>();

            commands.CreateCommand("greet")
                .Description("Does a thing")
                .Parameter("theGreeted", ParameterType.Unparsed)
                .Do(async (e)=> 
                {
                    var msgtoRead = e.Channel.DownloadMessages(1);

                    await e.Channel.SendTTSMessage("Hello " + e.GetArg("theGreeted"));
                });

            discord.UserUpdated += async (s, e) => {
                var channel = e.Server.FindChannels("general", ChannelType.Text).FirstOrDefault();
               string usrnm = e.After.Name;

                // This shouldn't get an error
                // But when I run the code I
                // get a Null Reference Exception

                if (e.After.VoiceChannel.Name != null)
                {
                    await channel.SendMessage(usrnm + " to " + e.After.VoiceChannel.Name);
                }
                else
                {

                    await channel.SendMessage(usrnm + " exited");
                }
            };


            discord.UserJoined += async (s, e) =>
            {
                var channel = e.Server.FindChannels("mainbois", ChannelType.Text).FirstOrDefault();
                var user = e.User;
                await channel.SendTTSMessage(string.Format("Another human has entered..."));
            };

            discord.ExecuteAndWait(async () =>
            {
                await discord.Connect("MYBOTTOKEN", TokenType.Bot);
            });
        }

        private void Log(object sender, LogMessageEventArgs e)
        {
        Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks in advance!

P.S. Please chastise if I made a simple error somewhere. :P

Comment: edit: `e.After.VoiceChannel` is null. I don't know enough about this event to say why.

Answer (score 1):

Found out that I can't check

```
if (e.After.VoiceChannel.Name != null)
```

if VoiceChannel is null. In other words, I can't check a value based on a null (if that makes any sense). My new code looks like

```
if (e.After.VoiceChannel != null)
```

Thanks to anyone who took the time to look at my code. :D